# Separation of variables for partial differential equations

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

What class of Partial Differential Equations can be solved using the method of separation of variables?

Comment: I've asked this question already and got no answer, I'm glad that you got a response.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extremely beautiful Lie-theoretic approach to separation of variables,
e.g. see Willard Miller's [book [1]](http://www.ima.umn.edu/%7Emiller/separationofvariables.html) (freely downloadable). I quote from his introduction:

> This book is concerned with the
> relationship between symmetries of a
> linear second-order partial
> differential equation of mathematical
> physics,  the coordinate systems in
> which the equation admits solutions
> via separation  of variables, and the
> properties of the special functions
> that arise in  this manner. It is an
> introduction intended for anyone with
> experience in  partial differential
> equations, special functions, or Lie
> group theory, such  as group
> theorists, applied mathematicians,
> theoretical physicists and  chemists,
> and electrical engineers. We will
> exhibit some modem group-theoretic
> twists in the ancient method of
> separation of variables that can be
> used to provide a foundation for much
> of special function theory. In
> particular, we will show explicitly
> that all special functions that arise
> via separation of variables in the
> equations of mathematical physics can
> be studied using group theory. These
> include the functions of Lam6, Ince,
> Mathieu, and others, as well as those
> of hypergeometric type.
>
> This is a very critical time in the
> history of group-theoretic methods in
> special function theory. The basic
> relations between Lie groups, special
> functions, and the method of
> separation of variables have recently
> been  clarified. One can now construct
> a group-theoretic machine that, when
> applied to a given differential
> equation of mathematical physics,
> describes  in a rational manner the
> possible coordinate systems in which
> the equation  admits solutions via
> separation of variables and the
> various expansion  theorems relating
> the separable (special function)
> solutions in distinct  coordinate
> systems. Indeed for the most important
> linear equations, the  separated
> solutions are characterized as common
> eigenfunctions of sets of
> second-order commuting elements in the
> universal enveloping algebra of  the
> Lie symmetry algebra corresponding to
> the equation. The problem of
> expanding one set of separable
> solutions in terms of another reduces
> to a  problem in the representation
> theory of the Lie symmetry algebra.

[1] Willard Miller. [Symmetry and Separation of Variables.](http://www.ima.umn.edu/%7Emiller/separationofvariables.html)
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1977 (out of print)

Answer (score 1):

For example the linear homogeneous PDEs with dependent variable $u$ and independent variables $x$ and $y$ , the separable condition is that the PDEs can rewrite to the form $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_1=0}^{b_1}M_{a_1}(x)X^{[a_1]}(x)}{\sum\limits_{a_2=0}^{b_2}N_{a_2}(x)X^{[a_2]}(x)}=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_3=0}^{b_3}P_{a_3}(y)Y^{[a_3]}(y)}{\sum\limits_{a_4=0}^{b_4}Q_{a_4}(y)Y^{[a_4]}(y)}$ when letting $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ .

For example, the PDE $x^2u_{xy}-yu_{yy}+u_x-4u=0$ mentioned in [The canonical form of a nonlinear second order PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67748) is an unseparable example while the PDE $u_{xy}-yu_{yy}+u_x-4u=0$ is a separable example.

Start from the PDEs with three independent variables, the separable conditions are more difficult to described, since for example the linear homogeneous PDEs with dependent variable $u$ and independent variables $x$ , $y$ and $z$ , the PDEs are separable when the PDEs not only can rewrite to the form $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_1=0}^{b_1}M_{1,a_1}(x)X^{[a_1]}(x)}{\sum\limits_{a_2=0}^{b_2}M_{2,a_2}(x)X^{[a_2]}(x)}+\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_3=0}^{b_3}M_{3,a_3}(y)Y^{[a_3]}(y)}{\sum\limits_{a_4=0}^{b_4}M_{4,a_4}(y)Y^{[a_4]}(y)}+\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_5=0}^{b_5}M_{5,a_5}(z)Z^{[a_5]}(z)}{\sum\limits_{a_6=0}^{b_6}M_{6,a_6}(z)Z^{[a_6]}(z)}=0$ when letting $u(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ , but also when the PDEs can rewrite to the form $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_1=0}^{b_1}M_{1,a_1}(x)X^{[a_1]}(x)}{\sum\limits_{a_2=0}^{b_2}M_{2,a_2}(x)X^{[a_2]}(x)}+\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_3=0}^{b_3}M_{3,a_3}(y)Y^{[a_3]}(y)}{\sum\limits_{a_4=0}^{b_4}M_{4,a_4}(y)Y^{[a_4]}(y)}+\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_3=0}^{b_3}N_{3,a_3}(y)Y^{[a_3]}(y)\sum\limits_{a_5=0}^{b_5}M_{5,a_5}(z)Z^{[a_5]}(z)}{\sum\limits_{a_4=0}^{b_4}N_{4,a_4}(y)Y^{[a_4]}(y)\sum\limits_{a_6=0}^{b_6}M_{6,a_6}(z)Z^{[a_6]}(z)}=0$ when letting $u(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ .